# How to say or in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to match two choices. "One or the other"

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE category='blue' || category='red' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

That is my first thought is to use

```
||
```

Comment: You can use [`||` and `OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) interchangeably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL does [support logical operators as well](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html).

By the way, you can shorten this statement to

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE category IN ('blue','red') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

use the word  `or` instead of `||`.